# How can I tell how often a DynamoDB throttled request succeeded?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When a request such as `dynamoClient.update(params)` is throttled, my understanding is that the SDK automatically attempts a number of retries and then the call fails only if all retries fail.  If one of them succeeds, then the call succeeds.

My question has to do with CloudWatch reporting throttled requests.  If a request originally fails, but one of the retires succeeds, is that reported as a throttled request?  Or does it only get reported as throttled only if all retries fail?

What I'm *really* trying to understand when looking at the behavior of my system is how often retries are occurring and whether they're eventually failing or succeeding.  When I see a report that 50 requests were throttled, does that mean all 50 failed all retries?  Or could some of those 50 have eventually succeeded? If the latter, how can I get a sense of how many eventually succeeded, and how many eventually completely failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudWatch metric **ThrottledRequests** [(full details)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html) is incremented each time a DynamoDB read/write operation failed because you'd hit your provisioned throughput limit. If the `aws-sdk` retries three times and succeeds on the third then`ThrottledRequests` is incremented by 2.

(n.b. there are some nuances when it comes to batch requests, which are outlined full in the linked docs).

Measurement of "failed requests because the sdk gave up" is a bit harder. This is because it the 'failures' have already been recorded as `ThrottledRequests`. Once the `aws-sdk` reaches the maximum number of configured retires, the request will fail. At this point you can log the failure, which you might then make available using a custom [CloudWatch metric](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/).

If you want to specifically measure "requests that retried but succeded" you can inspect the property `Response.retryCount` [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Response.html#retryCount-property) and log accordingly.